# Synchronize N number of child processes in Unix using pipes to print a message

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork, child-process

I have a school assignment that tells me to sync n number of processes using pipe's write and read, i know how to sync with 3 processes but right now I don't have a fixed number of children to be created.To sync 3 processes I used 3 pipes and 3 file descriptors but now I need to create a pipe and a file descriptor for each child but I don't know how many children I have because it is the users input. My question is how do I sync processes using pipes without knowing how many pipes do I need ?

I need to print the process number ,id and a loop counter forever until the users inputs ctrl^c

Update: I think i solved the problem of creating N pipes with N fd arrays, my real challenge is how to sync N processes to print the message by order from the first child to last one and not in random order

Update 2: i managed to sync the processes, but it doesn't loop and it hangs at the last process

I need help its been 5 days since i started and I am getting crazy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ptr=argv[1];
    char inbuf[5];
    int n=atoi(ptr);//number of processes to be created

    //int **fdArray;

    //fdArray= (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));


    //int fd[2];

    int fd[n][2];


    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        //fdArray[i]=fd;
        pipe(fd[i]);
    }

    write(fd[0][1],"d",1);

    //write gia na mplokareis to prwto pedi

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(fork()==0)
        {


            while(1)
            {
                read(fd[i][0],inbuf,1);
                write(fd[i+1][1],"d",1);
                printf("Process %d has process id %d i= %d \n",i,getpid(),i);   
                // an en i teleftea na gra4ei sti prwti alliws stin epomeni

                if(i==n-1)
                {    
                    write(fd[0][1],"d",1);
                    read(fd[i][0],inbuf,1);

                }

                else if(i<n)
                {
                    write(fd[i+1][1],"d",1);
                    read(fd[i][0],inbuf,1);
                }



            }

        }


    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        wait(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with arrays? You could maintain an array of file-descriptor pairs (and pids if you need them). Probably have to malloc it though for dynamic allocation.

Comment: Yes, i forgot to mention I am using fd[2] array but again it is not a fixed number, my number of pipes and fd arrays I have to create depends on the users input

Comment: right—so you perhaps need to dynamically allocate an array to store *all* your fds from the pipes... anytime you approach a problem of storing N related things, consider collections over individual variables.

Comment: Yes you are right, i will try it, thank you

Comment: "it hangs at the last process".  Probably because you aren't closing anything.  Whenever you call pipe/fork, be very careful to close everything.

Comment: Okay thanks, i will try and get back to you